# lock certain directories against deletion under $HOME directory

Tags: linux, file-permissions

Recently I have been install Arch linux on many people's laptops and desktops. All of them are happy with the look and feel, speed, and it has got more user friendly than windows.

But none of them have have any idea about any command. They don't even know what a terminal is. So I have to keep every GUI programs that I can think of.

One of them has recently deleted the dot files because he thought those files just sits there as it is, and he then ended up with the ugly XFCE default theme and all the configurations are gone. Even Firefox has to be setup from scratch now!

So in the future installation, I have decided to lock all the dot files under $HOME in a way that it's writeable but not deletable.

I am aware of the `chattr +i dir` command, which makes the directory immutable, I have also tried to follow [How to lock a file against deletion but still make it writeable?](https://superuser.com/questions/326873/how-to-lock-a-file-against-deletion-but-still-make-it-writeable)

But the solutions I explored so far aren't applicable in this case.

Any idea how to prevent folder deletion but keep them writeable under XFS and F2FS?

Comment: Why not roll them back to the last backup? So if they delete stuff, they suffer a bit but they suffer not enough to make them angry - this tends to have the best educational balance.

Comment: Yes, hardlinks can help in this case. But still, it's probably the safest option to lock directories, if that's possible at all...

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, but if it is, knowing the proper answer will also enlighten me. Surely there are other options if locking isn't possible at all! We can even write a program to copy files automatically (on a desktop icon click, watching directories' presence is expensive) once the folder has been deleted, but that's a different topic I think...

Comment: There are no hardlinks for directories - only for files.